# tikz tree use pic as tree node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This question does not aim to explore something meaningful, but just for some interest.

Is there a way to use a `pic` as a "tree node" directly? It means that I can reference the named node or coordinate in pic after the tree has been draw.

Consider following pic just for example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  test n/.store in=\test@n,
  test n=3,
  test/.pic={
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \ang using (\x-1)*360/\test@n] in {1, ..., \test@n} {
      \draw (0, 0) -- (\ang:5mm) coordinate (-\x);
    }
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic (a) [test n=6] {test};
  \draw[red] (a-1) -- (a-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to use this pic in several nodes of the tree and reference the coordinates such as `(a-1)` after, is there a possible way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap a `matrix` around the `pic`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  test n/.store in=\test@n,
  test n=3,
  pics/test/.style={code={
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \ang using (\x-1)*360/\test@n] in {1, ..., \test@n} {
      \draw (0, 0) -- (\ang:5mm) coordinate (-\x);
    }
  }}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {root}
    child {node[matrix] {\pic (a1) [test n=6] {test};\\}}
    child {node[matrix] {\pic (a2) [test n=6] {test};\\}
      child {node[matrix] {\pic (a3) [test n=6] {test};\\}}
      child {node[matrix] {\pic (a4) [test n=8] {test};\\}}
    };

  \draw[red] (a1-1) -- (a1-2);
  \draw[red] (a2-2) -- (a2-3);
  \draw[red] (a3-4) -- (a3-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works also with `forest`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  test n/.store in=\test@n,
  test n=3,
  pics/test/.style={code={
    \tikzset{test/.cd,#1}%
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \ang using (\x-1)*360/\test@n] in {1, ..., \test@n} {
      {\draw (0, 0) -- (\ang:5mm) coordinate (-\x);}
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/test/extra}  
    }
  }},test/.cd,extra/.code={}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[pft
 [{\pic (a1) [test n=6] {test};\\},matrix]
 [{\pic (a2) [test n=6] {test};\\},matrix]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is to access the named `pic`s from outside. `forest` does something to the `pic`s, and accessing the named `pic`s from outside is generally a bit tricky, so at this point I do not know how to solve that.

Comment: Can this trick be used in `forest` package?

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck I have not tried but would think so.

Comment: It seems that the content of `[...]` has been wrapped with node, I'm not familiar with `forest` package, but I know it is powerful. So I wonder how to do the same thing in this package.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck The basic trick works, accessing the nodes from outside is tricky.

Comment: It's ok, move to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548612/tikz-use-pic-as-tree-node-with-forest-package